# Bootstrap: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is messing with my head, this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".tour-popover").popover({html: true });
    $('#1-popover').popover('show');
    $('.next-popover').click(function(){
        cur_num = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10); 
        $('#'cur_num+'-popover').popover('destroy');                    
    });
});
```

The first time I use the `popover()` method to show it, it works fine, but if I want to destroy or hide it, it doesn't work and throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'`

This is how the files are called:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/custom-colors.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="files/main.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/main.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/bootstrap/file-upload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You seem to be loading your file (`main.js`) before you load bootstrap. You have to load bootstrap before you use it.

Comment: The js you see isn't in the main.js file, it's in script tags after bootstrap is loaded.

Comment: Can you show the HTML, so we can see what the jQuery selectors are selecting? You only initialize the elements selected by `$(".tour-popover")` ... Have the other elements that you work with (like `$('#1-popover')`) been initialized?